# ParallelLoopState - using Break not exiting current iteration, why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, task

I came across this example as I was learning about ParallelLoopState:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, (int i, ParallelLoopState loopState) =>
            {
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Breaking loop");
                    loopState.Break();
                    Console.WriteLine("LowestBreakIteration = " +
 loopState.LowestBreakIteration);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("i= " + i);

                });
```

A possible outcome of this is:

```
i= 6
i= 4
i= 0
Breaking loop
LowestBreakIteration = 5
i= 2
i= 8
i= 1
i= 3
i= 7
i= 5
```

Obviously each time the app is ran, a different outcome is generated.
How can it be possible that "LowestBreakIteration = 5" and "i=5" are separated by other values of i?
I thought that once `if (i==5)` is fulfilled, it goes directly to the next iteration, without ever writing i= 5 in the console (last line of code: `Console.WriteLine("i= " + i);`).
According to the book: "Break ensures that all iterations that are currently running will be finished"

Answer (score 2):

That's because all other iterations are already started. If you want to stop all operations you need to use `loopState.Stop()` instead of `loopState.Break()`

`loopState.Break()` means complete all iterations on all threads that are prior to the current iteration on the current thread, and then exit the loop.

`loopState.Stop()` means stop all iterations as soon as convenient.